# Cleanly asserting a specific part of a config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert, python-3.5

I want to `assert` the existance certain values in my config file, but I don't want to make every other line an `assert` statement. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
assert config["email"]["address"], "You must supply email information."

assert config["email"]["address"], "You must supply an address to receive."
self.addresses = config["email"]["address"]

self.smtpserver = config.get["email"].get("smtpserver", "smtp.gmail.com:587")

assert config["email"]["sender"], "You must a sender for your email."
self.sender = config["email"]["sender"]

assert config["email"]["password"], "You must supply an email password"
self.password = config["email"]["password"]
```

The config:

```
  "email": {
    "address": [
      "someone@place.potato"
    ],
    "smtpserver": "smtp.potato.com:567",
    "sender": "someoneelse@place.potato",
    "password": "sup3rg00dp455w0rd"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical method for ensuring JSON data conforms specific format is to use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org).

While Python does not have built-in package to handle JSON schemas, there is [`jsonschema`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) available at PyPi.

Usage is rather straightforward. I'm quoting samples from PyPi here:

```
from jsonschema import validate
schema = {
     "type" : "object",
     "properties" : {
         "price" : {"type" : "number"},
         "name" : {"type" : "string"},
     },
}

# If no exception is raised by validate(), the instance is valid.
validate({"name" : "Eggs", "price" : 34.99}, schema)

validate({"name" : "Eggs", "price" : "Invalid"}, schema) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
ValidationError: 'Invalid' is not of type 'number'
```